# Reading/Writing ElevationAngle in Kinect throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-interaction

Any idea how to move the Kinect up and down? Theoretically,

```
sensor.ElevationAngle = 20;
```

should do the job, but I am getting the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException
This API has returned an exception from an HRESULT: 0x8007000D
```

It breaks down even if e.g. reading the current ElevationAngle is the first thing after starting the Kinect Sensor... (the answer to [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603394/setting-kinects-elevationangle-randomly-throws-com-based-invalidoperationexcept) suggests it's because of too much movement operations but it happens even if the Kinect has not adjusted position for some time; if it's duplicating, I am sorry, but I am unable to comment the above mentioned question).

** edit ** code:

```
using Microsoft.Kinect;

namespace pro02_01_streams.tilt
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for Tilt_test.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Tilt_test : Window
{
    private KinectSensor sensor;
    public Tilt_test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Test();
    }

    public void Test(){

         if (KinectSensor.KinectSensors.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Kinects presents", "Error");
            Application.Current.Shutdown();

        }
        try
        {
            sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
            sensor.DepthStream.Enable();
            sensor.ColorStream.Enable();

            sensor.Start();
            sensor.ElevationAngle = 1;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to initialize kinect", "error");
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does the Kinect work without changing the ElavationAngle? Could you please post the full code.

Comment: @Kevin Streaming works fine. I want to have a simple application that displays the video and enables user to move kinect up and down by button controls. 

Is there a possibility that the motor is just broken and this is why the exception is thrown? If so, how can I check that it is really "mechanical" problem?

If it is still necessary I will paste the full code later on when I have the access to the computer with this project, but it is pretty much a copy-paste from some tutorial to which I added 
`sensor.ElevationAngle =20` when user clicks some button on the main panel.

Comment: I hear you are changing the angle with buttons. Check if your start the Kinect in the same thread in comparison with where you change the angle.

Comment: @KevinCloet - I edited the post with the code sample. It is the program that doesn't even use buttons. Still, there is an error.

Comment: I don't really see a problem with that code. Does the elevationangle work with one of those tutorials? Maybe open one of the examples apps in the Developer toolkit. If I remember I'm going to try and run your code tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. To find out if your Kinect works properly, open the Kinect Developer Toolkit Browser and run the Kinect Explorer-WPF. In the application, go to Sensor Settings and move your Kinect with desired angle.

Comment: at first I thought that the device might be faulty, but in SDK developer it works ok. For the time being when I need to have sensor move in my app I develop it by changing the SDK example which is ...
I have no idea why such simple code won't work in my new apps ..

Comment: Well, there must be some tiny detail, that has been overlooked. All the samples in the Developer Toolkit can be installed and the source code is for you to learn how to correctly work with the Kinect. Try to open the source code and examine different approaches in your project. The very basic steps can be found in the **ColorBasics** or **DepthBasics** project. And the next step for some UI controls interaction the **ControlsBasics** project was very helpful for me. SensorChooser class makes almost everything for you.